# cannot show correct amount of decimal numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I have to create a simple number rounding tool for my school project.
It lets the user decide how many decimals to round a given number.

I can't get my code to round the user's input (`number`) to the given decimals (`decimalammount`).

It's just showing the default 2 decimals every time :(
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Clear();
    while (true)
    {
        string input;
        decimal number;
        int decimalammount;

        Console.WriteLine("Rounderuperer");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to round:");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        number = decimal.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of decimals you wish to round to:");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        decimalammount = int.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:f} Rounded to {1:g} decimals = {2:f}", number, decimalammount, Math.Round(number, decimalammount, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        Console.WriteLine("Press <Spacebar> to round another number . . .");
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a sample for your inputs and desired output.

Comment: what is the specific problem you´re facing? Does the above code produce an error? If so, what is your input and your expeced result?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You post is quite good for a new contributor. What would make it perfect if you would write something along the lines of: "if I input the number 2.123456 and enter 4 for the number of decimals, I get the output of 2.12. But I expect it to be 2.1235"

Comment: Use following : Console.WriteLine("{0} Rounded to {1:g} decimals = {2}", number, decimalammount, Math.Round(number, decimalammount, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString());

Comment: @jdweng I think the `ToString()` call is superfluous here, since it will be called anyway when the format of input string to `WriteLine` is parsed

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys, sorry if my question was badly written!
Big thank you to Mong Zhu, your answer was very informative, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Problem is the `f` for the format of numbers. The [documentation of numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) says the following:

> "F" or "f"    Fixed-point Result: Integral and decimal digits with optional negative sign.
> Supported by: All numeric types.
> Precision specifier: Number of decimal digits.
> **Default precision specifier**: Defined by **NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits**.

The [NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigit documentation tells us](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits?view=netcore-3.1):

> The number of decimal places to use in numeric values. The default for InvariantInfo is 2.

So this is the reason why you get always those 2 decimal places.

The simplest solution would be to remove the format entirely. Actually also in the first number, since you probably want it to be displayed with all its decimals

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} Rounded to {1:g} decimals = {2}", number, decimalammount, Math.Round(number, decimalammount, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```